# Which has better performance, join or subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have written a query using both a join and a subquery, but I don't know which has better performance. Would you tell me?

My query using a subquery:

```
SELECT e.e_id,e.name,e.email, (SELECT mc.m_id FROM table3 AS mc WHERE e.mobile = mc.c_mobile AND e.status=0 AND mc.currentdate<= e.currentdate LIMIT 1 ) AS cm_id
FROM table1 AS e
INNER JOIN table3 AS m
ON e.e_id = m.m_id AND m.m_status = 1
WHERE e.city LIKE 'wgl' AND e.status >= 0
GROUP BY e.email
ORDER BY e.status ASC, e.currentdate DESC
```

My query using joins:

```
SELECT e.e_id,e.name,e.manager_id,mc.m_id AS cm_id
FROM table1 AS e
LEFT JOIN table3 AS mc
ON e.mobile = mc.c_mobile AND e.status=0 AND mc.currentdate <= e.currentdate
INNER JOIN table2 AS m
ON e.manager_id = m.m_id AND m.m_status = 1
WHERE e.city LIKE 'wgl' AND e.status >= 0
GROUP BY e.email
ORDER BY e.status ASC, e.currentdate DESC
```

Which performs better? How can I know which is best?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is "because the SQL engine is better at optimising some queries than others". So the way you're doing it is alright: just test and see if the difference in time is significant. Otherwise, there's no clear-cut answer.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` so MySQL can tell you what it does. It also tells you which is faster. It's much quicker doing that than asking on SO. Also, you can find this advice in nearly every MySQL-related query performance question, please do your research before asking.

Comment: I tested it using EXPLAIN it shows select type simple for joins and primary for subquery what it means.It does not show executing time.How can I see time.

Comment: Share the `EXPLAIN` result if you want help understanding it. Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to test the time. These queries aren't equivalent. They don't yield the same results.

Comment: I executed using SQL_NO_CACHE but it returns different execution times on each execution .

Comment: That's normal. Use the average time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, by default, uses the [Block Nested-Loop](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html#bnl-optimization) join algorithm for joins.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.col1
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t2.id = t1.id
```

In effect, yields the same performance as a subquery like the following:

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT col1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
FROM table1 t1
```

Indexes are obviously important to satisfy the `WHERE` clause in the subquery, and are used in the same fashion for join operations.